# Intersection Observer detects wrong amount of intersecting images after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

**EDIT: I worked on my functions and updated them in this post accordingly**

I want to implement lazy loading for images to a website. These images are in different galleries, which get loaded asynchronously, depending on which gallery the user wants to see.

My problem is that sometimes the `IntersectionObserver` reports all images as intersecting.

This is my `lazy load` function:

```
function lazyLoad(lazyImgs) {
  console.log('lazyLoad fired', lazyImgs);

  const imgOptions = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px'
  };

  const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, imgObserver) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        let lazyImage = entry.target;
        let sources = lazyImage.children;

        for (let s = 0; s < sources.length; s++) {
          let source = sources[s];

          console.log('intersecting: ', source);

          imgObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
      } // end is intersecting
    });
  }, imgOptions);

  lazyImgs.forEach(img => {
    imgObserver.observe(img);
  });
} // end lazyLoad();
```

`lazyLoad();` gets invoked at the end of this function, when the content has loaded:

```
function getContent(url) {
  url = url.split('#');
  link = url[1] + '.php';

  // load content into the content-wrapper
  let str = $('.content-wrapper').load('inc.galleries/' + link, function(
    responseTxt,
    statusTxt,
    xhr
  ) {
    if (statusTxt == 'error') {
      console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
  });

  // Convert the HTML string into a document object
  let $contentWrapper = $('.content-wrapper');
  html = $.parseHTML(str);
  nodeName = [];

  // Append the parsed HTML
  $contentWrapper.append(html);

  // when Ajax request is complete...
  // ...get all images with a class of lazyImgs and run lazyLoad function :)
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    let lazyImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyImg');
    lazyLoad(lazyImgs);
  });
}
```

`let lazyImgs` returns to me a node list with all picture elements with a class of `lazyImg`, so the `DOM` seems to have been updated successfully. But the `IntersectionObserver` still can't tell which images are inside the viewport.

**EDIT 2:** I'm suspecting it could be that the `IntersectionObserver` detects the images as intersecting when they load and therefore don't have their full size, yet. Does anyone have an idea how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the issue is and have a - I think - reasonable solution. Maybe this helps someone else:

The `CSS` for the images I was using has a `fixed` `height`. But the `width` was set to `auto` and apparently that caused the images to have `width: 0;` on load. That's why the `IntersectionObserver` reported them all as intersecting (since they were, in fact, all on the screen, if only for a brief moment).

I then set a `min-width` on the images. It's not ideal. But with only one `Media Query` at `900px` the pictures scale just fine and the `IntersectionObserver` recognizes the correct number of images inside the viewport.

```
.gallery-img img {
  margin: 0 0.14rem;
  min-width: 25rem;
  width: auto;
  height: 68vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .gallery-img img {
    min-width: 20rem;
  }
}
```

As I said, it's not ideal. But it does the job. If anyone has a better solution, I would appreciate to see it!